Why aren't material shaders applying to certain objects in the scene?
thanks for your help. I am new to this community and have to ask for assistance with a project of mine that I need to complete.
I have a project with lots of objects and small pieces and layers. I know when some of you look at the setup it will appear messy. I apologize for I am rather new to blender and only know so much.
The issue arises when I try to apply textures to a few certain objects in the scene. No matter what I seem to do they can't change to the correct ones.


The highlighted/outlined object is just one of the many in the scene that I can't seem to apply a new texture to.
Some objects that are the exact same, just SHIFT-D duplicates, have no issue when I apply the textures but there are some that just won't change. I have no idea what is going on.

Please help.
EDIT: Here is a setup of a texture that works and shows up in Texture View


Here is one that does not show up.



Also I apologize, I am unsure how to link the actual Blender file itself. If someone would like to take a look at it I am more than happy to share so we can solve this together. Thank you.

Are you missing a material assignation by any chance ? Can you please give a view of your node editor for the material attached to this object (if you have one) :)

@Shaddo I have edited the post to show what I think you are looking for. If not, please let me know. Thank you for getting back so quickly.

All good, well it seems you don't have any textures connected. Are you trying to swap materials instead ?

@Shaddo Yes. For example that small torus object in the bottom of the screenshot. When I click on it the object says it has Metal 1 as the texture but it doesn't look any different. I can swap it for the gold texture or even create a new one but nothing changes.

As I can see, you have 24 copies of your material 'Metal 1', can you try switching materials using the icon on the left of the material name until a texture shows up ?

@Shaddo I just tried doing that and I can't seem to get anything to work. The blend file .5 mb too large for me to upload so I apologize. I am beginning to think I will need to rework all of this.

@Shaddo Hey I wanted to say thanks for helping me out. After quite a bit of experimentation I figured it out. It seems I had multiple copies of the same object overlayed on itself and I needed to delete those before I could actually see the textured object properly.

If you expand the Material's Preview, does it look like (Metal or Gold)?  The tiny material icon looks black to me.  That might provide a clue.

Glad to see you made it :) @Runel0rd
